# Инжект бина из другого проекта

Tags: java, spring

Существуют 2 модуля. Первый модуль зависит от второго. В первом есть Configuration класс, в котором определяются бины. Как создать бин, компонентом которого является бин из другого модуля ?

1 Проект :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("md.model);
public class OfficeConfig {

@Bean
public OfficeTemplate officeTemplateProvider(ConnectionProperties connection){
return new OfficeTemplate(connection);
}
}
```

2 Проект :

```
@Component
public class ConnectionProperties {
...
}
```

UPD : во втором модуле нет файла конфигурации.

Comment: Если во втором есть класс с аннотацией `@Configuration`, который попадает в сканирование, то создавать бин не надо. Его достаточно лишь внедрить при помощи `@Autowired`. В противном случае его требуется определять руками в первом модуле.

Comment: @Темкатоже , во втором модуле нет класса конфигурации, но есть класс , который объявлен с аннотацией @ Component. Пробовал его заинжектить через @ Import, но не работает.

Comment: Класс, который объявлен как `@Component` можно внедрять аналогично. Не могу понять, зачем тебе понадобился `@Import`. Приведи реальный код.

Comment: @Темкатоже добавил.

Comment: если `ConnectionProperties` находится в пакете `md.model`, то это должно работать, если нет, то добавь пакет в список сканируемых.